# A ConnectionFactory for provider 'twitter' has already been registered

Tags: java, facebook, twitter, spring-boot, spring-social

I'm overriding the default Spring Boot configuration for Spring Social Twitter and Facebook. I'm getting the following error when I run the application.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactoryLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/social/config/annotation/SocialConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator]: Factory method 'connectionFactoryLocator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ConnectionFactory for provider 'twitter' has' already been registered
```

I have a feeling that this is happening because of some conflict with the default config. The code is as follows, how can I solve this problem?

SocialConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer{

protected static final String FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "spring.social.facebook.appId";
protected static final String FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = "spring.social.facebook.appSecret";

protected static final String TWITTER_APP_ID = "spring.social.twitter.appId";
protected static final String TWITTER_APP_SECRET = "spring.social.twitter.appSecret";
private DataSource dataSource;

@Inject
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer,Environment env) {
    connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(getFacebookConnectionFactory(env));
    connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(getTwitterConnectionFactory(env));
}

@Override
public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
    return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
}

@Override
public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
    return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
}


protected final FacebookConnectionFactory getFacebookConnectionFactory(Environment env) {
    String appId = env.getProperty(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
    String appSecret = env.getProperty(FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);

    if(appId == null || appId.isEmpty())
        throw new ApplicationPropertyException();

    if (appSecret == null || appSecret.isEmpty())
        throw new ApplicationPropertyException();

    return new FacebookConnectionFactory(appId, appSecret);
}


protected final TwitterConnectionFactory getTwitterConnectionFactory (Environment env){
    String consumerKey = env.getProperty(TWITTER_APP_ID);
    String consumerSecret = env.getProperty(TWITTER_APP_SECRET);

    if(consumerKey == null || consumerKey.isEmpty())
        throw new ApplicationPropertyException();

    if (consumerSecret == null || consumerSecret.isEmpty())
        throw new ApplicationPropertyException();

    return new TwitterConnectionFactory(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
}


protected DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}
```

}

AppConfig

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppConfig{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args); 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Boot's auto-configuration for Spring Social Twitter and Spring Social Facebook will automatically add connection factories based on the configuration in `application.properties`. These auto-configured connection factories are clashing with those that you're trying to add.

The ones that you're trying to add have the same configuration as those that Spring Boot is creating for you. I'd recommend removing your configuration and letting Boot do its thing. Change `SocialConfig` to extend `SocialConfigurerAdapter` rather than implementing `SocialConfigurer` then delete your `addConnectionFactories` method.

Comment: how does Spring boot know which configuration lines are containing the appsecret for facebook for example?

Comment: @Maurice : we need to specify those appsecret keys in `application.properties` file